Can I create a file other than route.js in next js backend
I want to create a file name ask.js in the backend of next js but it is not accessible (not found 404) until I renamed it to route js
Then for each controller I have to create a seperate folder and route.js file ??
What is the folder structure which should be followed to set up next.js backend.

Route handlers work similarly as regular pages when it comes to routing.
Yes, the route file must be named route.(ts|js) and you cannot change that. To control the URL to which the route responds, you must place it inside a folder structure that matches the path in the URL.
So if you have the file: app/api/ask/route.ts, the URL path for this route would be /api/ask.
Keep in mind that you cannot have a page.ts and a route.ts at the same folder.
